# Track Facebook app installs through ads

Tags: ios, facebook, ads

We are looking for a way to track if the current user comes from a Facebook ad. Is there a way to achieve that?

We need to set this info in our database in order to make queries on these people (cohorts).

I found some similar questions :

- [Here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13012025/track-mobile-facebook-ads-to-create-cohort-of-users)
- And [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15708721/track-install-from-facebook-sdk-came-from-facebook).

We are not looking for [external services](https://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/mobile/measurement/), we need to have this info in our database to create cohorts.

P.S: We are already tracking installs with `[FBSettings publishInstall:FACEBOOK_APP_ID];`

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: Unformtunatly no, i'm still interested if someone managed to achieve that..

Comment: Anyone please answer this question, most of the developers face this issue

Comment: Have you looked at the FBAppEvents class?

Comment: As far as i understand the FBAppEvent class only send data from your app to facebook. How can you get the info that current user is coming from a facebook ad ?

Comment: Has anyone managed to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

While reverse engineering some Tracking frameworks I found that most of them are getting the Facebook Attribute ID (Advertiser ID) from the pasteboard. It seems that Facebook is setting that after the ad is touched.

I couldn't find any documentation but the Facebook SDK has a class *FBUtility* with an *attributionID* class method.

```
+ (NSString *)attributionID 
{
    return [[UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"fb_app_attribution" create:NO] string];
}
```